# Fetching Documents from Mongo Collection using Karras

Tags: mongodb, clojure

Let's assume that I have a collection in mongodb, where all of its documents take the following structure.

```
{
    "_id":5,
    "key-name":"test",
    "meta-data":{
        "user-id":2,
        "status":2
    }
}
```

Let assume I want to find all collections where **"user-id" = 2**. I can do this easily Via the mongo shell using following function.

```
db.mycol.find({"meta-data.user-id" : 2})
```

I need to retrieve these documents via clojure. Therefore, I have the following set of functions.

Following are my code so far I have.

```
(ns demo.repository
  (:use karras.core)
  (:use karras.sugar)
  (:use karras.collection))

(def mongo-connection (atom nil))
(def mandate-db (atom nil))

(defn mongo-connect []
  (if (nil? @mongo-connection)
    (do
      (swap! mongo-connection (constantly (connect "192.168.0.6" 27017)))
      (swap! mandate-db (constantly (mongo-db @mongo-connection "mydb"))))))

(defn mongo-close []
  (if-not (nil? @mongo-connect)
    (.close @mongo-connect)))

(defn- job-collection [] (collection @mandate-db "mycol"))

(defn retrieve-doc [id]
  (fetch (job-collection) {"meta-data.user-id" id}))
```

**retrieve-doc** is the function I intent to use to fetch documents. The following function does the job.

```
(fetch (job-collection) {"meta-data.user-id" id})
```

**And this is how you can solve this with [Karras](https://github.com/wilkes/karras)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer:

```
(fetch (job-collection) {"meta-data.user-id" id})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(fetch (job-collection) {:meta-data {:user-id id}})
```